# langchain : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'langchain_community'

Tags: python, langchain

Trying to execute this code:

from langchain_community.vectorstores import FAISS

Error it is showing:
**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'langchain_community'**

Thou I have executed the command:

> **pip install langchain-community**

Answer (score 3):

```
pip install langchain-community langchain-core
```

This is required.

If still not working then:

```
pip install --upgrade langchain
```

Also, make sure that **python_version=>3.8.1**